# Determine appropriate parent type for function argument in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have code that looks like this (part way through a refactoring)

```
void doSomething( DerivedType v ) {
  v.foo();
  v.bar();
  ...
}

public static class DerivedType extends Parent1 {
  @Override void foo() { ... }
}

public static class Parent1 extends Parent2 {
  public void foo() {...}
  public void bar() {...}
}

public static class Parent2 {
  public void bar() { ... }
}
```

In this case the function signature for `doSomething` is overly restrictive. It will only accept a `DerivedType` even though it only uses functionality available in `Parent1`.

It would seem sensible to change

```
void doSomething(DerivedType v){
...
}
```

to

```
void doSomething(Parent1 v){
...
}
```

and everything should still work, since `doSomething` only uses functions defined in `Parent1`. There would not even be any changes needed at the points where `doSomething` is called.

Note that it could not be changed to `void doSomething(Parent2 v){...}` since `v.foo` doesn't exist in `Parent2`.

**Is there a way for eclipse to tell me that the argument type of `doSomething` could be changed from `DeriedType` to `Parent1`?**

In this case it's pretty obvious, but in reality, `doSomething` is several hundred lines long, and the type hierachy for `DerivedType` is much deeper, pulling in several interfaces as it goes - so a quick way to do this could save me a fair bit of time. (Probably not as long as its taken me to type this question out, but learning is important ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its super-easy.

- Cursor on desired parameter,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, (Refactor menu)
- "Generalize Declared Type".

Then you can select `Parent1` from the list.